# Display Unicode String in JTable

Tags: java, swing, unicode, internationalization, jtable

I have a Unicode string that contains Japanese characters. If I try to display it in my JTable, I get square brackets instead of the characters. Is there a way to display the characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340739/setting-unicode-characters-in-java-frames/340759#340759), maybe it's what you want, too.

Comment: Very cool. Next step it to allow different fonts on different cells.

Comment: After a little search, i found this with two interesting links: http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/11594-set-different-font-each-cell-jtable.html

Comment: Perfect, that did the job. Thanks for your help.