# Recommended font(s) for displaying unicode characters?

Tags: java, swing, unicode, fonts

For anyone that has developed a customer-facing Java Swing application that supports multiple languages, which font(s) did you find best displayed the characters for all languages?

Comment: never need to solve that somhow on Windows OS +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See wikipedia on [unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font). It has a nice list and a comparison chart of unicode fonts. It seems GNU Unifont support most of the languages.

Answer (score 3):

You should also read [Loading Font Configuration Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/fontconfig.html) on font configuration with Java 6. This file allows you to specify which font can be used to represent glyphs from a specific locale. I had to use and configure it once, and it really helped me.

Comment: I forgot to mention I found that information thanks to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340739/setting-unicode-characters-in-java-frames) question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create your own?

You can create your own fonts with tools like the **[Icomoon App](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select)**. This app allows you to do each of the following :

- Get one or more icons from several popular icon fonts
- Upload other fonts, which may be icon fonts but also regular fonts
- Combine any number of icons from any number of available fonts
- Set the UNICODE hex value for whichever characters you need
- Export and/or save the font set you create

I used the Icomoon App to create the **[Emoji emoticon font](https://github.com/jslegers/emoji-icon-font)**. I also use it for creating custom icon fonts on a per project basis, but it can also be used to create custom fonts that support exactly those languages you need to support.